# Where to repair baby stroller in Nîmes or elsewhere in France?

Tags: france, children

So we are travelling with a child, and our baby stroller's wheel went bad. How do we find a place which fixes those in France? We have a popular model so I assume they should be able to replace it right away.

I'm trying to google `poussette reparer "nîmes"` but to my dismay it mainly shows baby shops list, then proceeds with iPhone repair and some random forums. What do I google to get proper results? Maybe you could fish some addresses for me right away? Preferably around Nîmes center.

Comment: Could you describe what "went bad" means? Would be easier to find a solution/proper shop if the malfunction was specified. Needing a replacement wheel or just some grease makes a difference.

Comment: It will be difficult to find a shop dedicated to repairing stroller as this is not common in France.

Comment: Wheel started turning with force and making noises. I think wheel replacement would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to find a Repair Cafe. There appears to be one in Nîmes (https://repaircafe.org/fr/location/repair-cafe-de-nimes), but their [website](https://www.lespetitsdebrouillardsoccitanie.org/spip.php/?article651) doesn't look entirely up to date.

Comment: They exist and occassionally fix strollers, but not on the spot. I think it was the best shot we had.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find repair shops specialized in strollers and I can't imagine that the employees in a baby/children shop are able to help you on the spot. If you return a defective stroller, they would either replace it or have to return it to the manufacturer for repair. That is not an option if you need a quick fix.

Your easiest option is probably to buy a new stroller. If that is not feasible or too expensive, I can imagine that you might get help in a bicycle repair shop. They will unlikely have special replacement parts for strollers, but if something can be repaired and does not have to be replaced, they may be able to fix whatever is jammed.